# Error Inaccessible due to its protection level. Only public types can be processed - when using XmlSerialiser for internal class

Tags: c#, class, object, xml-serialization

I have a number of internal classes in a library DLL that I'm creating.  These classes have access via some public methods.  A sample internal class is;

```
internal class MyClass
{
    internal int Id {get;set;}
    internal string Name {get;set;}
}
```

I need to serialise the object before being returned to the public method.  I'm trying to use the XmlSerialise method like

```
System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer x = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(MyObject.GetType());
```

But when I try this I get the error

> Error Inaccessible due to its protection level. Only public types can be processed

How can I overcome this problem, because I want to keep these internal classes private within the library DLL, and they can only be access using the public methods.

Comment: I was of the understanding that Internal classes or members are accessible only within files in the same assembly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Serializing internal types using XmlSerializer**

Solution here: https://web.archive.org/web/20160108180230/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sowmy/archive/2008/10/04/serializing-internal-types-using-xmlserializer.aspx

> Being able to serialize internal types is one of the common requests
>   seen by the XmlSerializer team. It is a reasonable request from people
>   shipping libraries. They do not want to make the XmlSerializer types
>   public just for the sake of the serializer.